# How does vscode get Type Inference Result during using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, type-inference

I hava write some code write in vscode like:

```js
function sum(a:number, b:number) {
  return a + b
}
```

Meanwhile, vscode give the user some tips which contains Type inference of this function return value.

[image]
How does vscode get that auto type inference result, is there some lib or typescript API can get result?

Comment: I think it ask you to type the return of the function so it should be function sum(a:number, b:number): number {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VS code has TypeScript language server.
You can find it in the bottom right corner
[image]

[Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide) you can find more information about language servers in VS Code